# lisp self-developed recursive reverse function

Tags: function, lisp, reverse

I have writte a list reverse function in lisp and I wanted to test it but I had an error and I couldn't solve it 
the function and calling is below :

```
    (defun myreverse (list)
    (cond((null list) nil))
    (cons (myreverse(cdr list) (car list))))


    (myreverse '(1 2 3))
```

any help will be appreciated...

Comment: What is the error? You also might want to format the code so that it is better readable. No, lining up all expressions at the first column is not readable.

Comment: the error is "too many arguments given to MYREVERSE" ,sorry I had forgotten to add the error to my question

Comment: Well, there are too many arguments to the function `myreverse` in your code. The error message is pretty clear. Why not just fix it?

Comment: How i can fix it ??

Answer (score 0):

The arguments when you `defun` `myreverse` are `(list)`, thus when you call it `(myreverse '(1 2 3))` `list` gets bound to `(1 2 3)`.

Since the list is not null you suddenly do `(myreverse '(2 3) 1)` and `list` gets bound to `(2 3)`, but what do `1` get bound to? You have no more than one argument thus the call is invalid and warrants an error.

Hint1: There is a way to make optional arguments:

```
(defun test (a &optional (b 0) (c 0))
  (+ a b c))

(test 10)     ; ==> 10
(test 10 1 2) ; ==> 13
```

Hint2: You need to build a list not just pass a bare element. The passed list will be the tail of the next round until the every element is added.

Answer (score 0):

The bad answer (or one of the bad answers):

```
(defun reverse (list)
    (cond ((null list) list)
          (t (append (reverse (cdr list)) (cons (car list) nil)))))
```

A better answer:

```
(defun reverse (list)
     (reverse-aux list nil))
(defun reverse-aux (list result)
     (cond ((null list) result)
           (t (reverse-aux (cdr list) (cons (car list) result)))))
```

It's the basic example we use in comparison to the definition of 'append' in lessons to differentiate tail recursion.